# Connecting two Ubuntu Virtual machines on private Ethereum network, can't get the two nodes to read each other

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3j

I am trying to connect two ubuntu vm as two ethereum nodes using geth. Addpeer doesn't work and bootnode isn't responding to one of the VMs. Note that I ssh accessed the other VM and can telnet the IPV4 through 22 tcp port

Comment: You need to open the p2p ports : I think it’s 3003 for both tcp and duo

Comment: even if the firewall status is inactive?

Comment: If they are in the same network it shouldn’t matter

Comment: So, I am able to access the other VM through ssh username@IPV4 address.

Comment: make sure to open the 30303 port and test if both nodes are listening on it.